# IOS/Objective-C: Pass UIImage from background to main queue

Tags: ios, multithreading, variables

I go out onto the web to grab an image in a background queue.  If the image is found, I would like to work with it in the main queue.  However, I am finding that my objects in the main queue are not recognized in the background queue.  I think I need to use block variables but I find those very confusing.  Can anyone suggest proper way to pass image downloaded from web back to main queue?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
UIImage*myImage; //image object I want to use on main queue.
  dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{ //open 4
                NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:picURL]];
                if (imgData) { //open 5  Is download complete?
                    UIImage *imageFromWeb = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                    if (imageFromWeb) { //open 6
                        NSLog(@"we got an image from contact pic url%@ and will now save it",picURL);
                        [self saveImage:imageFromWeb asPicName:picname];
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //open 7
                            myImage = imageFromWeb; //THROWS ERROR HERE 'variable is not assignable...'

                        }); //close 7
                    } //close 6
                } //close 5
            }); //close 4
```

Comment: The issue is not background / main queue, it's the scope of the variable. Is this in a function? You need to include the surrounding code to get help.

Comment: If you're going to define a local `UIImage` variable outside of the `dispatch_async`, you need to declare the local variable with `__block` qualifier. Or make it a property of the class, in which case no qualifier is needed.

Comment: what is the syntax for declaring with __block qualifier and where do you do this?

Comment: Adding __block UIImage*myImage; as a prefix should do

Comment: Yep. But why use a local variable? It's an asynchronous call (`dispatch_async`), so you've presumably left the function by the time you hit the setting of `myImage`. If you need a reference elsewhere, make it a property of the class. If you you don't need a reference to this elsewhere, then define the `myImage` variable _inside_ the `dispatch_async`. This code just doesn't quite make sense: Why you are determined to asynchronously set a local variable for a function that you've already left?

Comment: The myImage was set earlier on the main thread and has a default placeholder value if there is no image found on the web.  While the image is being sought on the web,  which can take a few seconds, the user sees the placeholder in the interim.  Then the change is made back on the main thread if the image is found.

Comment: Yeah, but why bother updating a local var in an async method? If it's local var, a reference you lose when you leave the function, anyway, so why bother updating it? If you were talking about a ivar or property (e.g. you needed to keep a reference to the image for some reason), that's fine. But you don't need `__block` for that. You only need it for local variables, and it doesn't make sense in this context. Hey, do whatever works for you, but using `__block` for asynchronous call is code smell, suggesting some deeper misunderstanding.